# Issue in implementing the Russel rust library

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, linear-algebra

I am trying to use the rust library called russel (https://github.com/cpmech/russell) in Fedora 35.
This library depends on the following libraries\packages:

- liblapacke-dev
- libopenblas-dev

I can install those on Debian however I am not able install them via dnf in Fedora, someone knows how to use install those packages or a workaround for them?

N.B When I try to compile the rust programme calling a Russel crates the following error is shown:

```
Compiling progamme v0.1.0 (/home/mattia/Downloads/programme)
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-m64" "................"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenblas
          /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapacke
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          

error: could not compile `programme` due to previous error
```

Comment: Try `lapack-devel` and `openblas-devel`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the libraries lapack-devel and openblas-devel installed using:

```
sudo dnf install lapack-devel openblas-devel
```

has solved the problems and the compilation has terminated correctly.

N.B: Only compiling directly from terminal worked, since I have installed VS code as flatpak package and it does see only system libraries, concluding with the same error in its integrated terminal